# Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have got the below error in Remix for function written in Solidity.

I think it is because the smart contract was written with a version of solidity below solidity ^0.5.0 and now the more up to date compilers have different requirements.

I'm sure the correction is easy but I am new to solidity and cannot seem to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated!

The external function is;

```
 function TransferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    bytes _data
  )
    external;
```

The error is:

```
Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, 
but none was given.
bytes _data
^----------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark `bytes _data` as `calldata`.

```
function TransferFrom(
address _from,
address _to,
uint256 _tokenId,
bytes calldata _data
) external;
```